# Ruby: take the Nth element from the array if it exists (in 1 line of code)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am parsing HTML. For example:

```
country_code = data.match(/Country Abbrev. : ([A-Z]{2})/)[1]
```

This seems to be the shortest way to get the value I am looking for. However, what if the data is not found (nil) and I am requesting for the second element of the array which does not exist?

What I want do do: if the returned object is not an array of at least two elements, country_code should be nil, otherwise, country_code = array[1].

What is the best way to solve this? Maybe where is a better way in Ruby to deal with such kind of regex lookups, when you need exactly one value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, this code does the thing:

```
country_code = data.match(/Country Abbrev. : ([A-Z]{2})/).to_a[1]
```